# Constructors C++, What does the colon after a constructor mean?

Tags: c++, constructor

Skimming through some code I noticed something I honestly can't wrap my head around in a constructor.
`class Terrain
{
public:
  Terrain(int movementCost,
          bool isWater,
          Texture texture)
  : movementCost_(movementCost),
    isWater_(isWater),
    texture_(texture)
  {}
... //More code`
What sort of wizardry is this? Are those `foo_(foo)` representing `foo = foo_`?

Comment: See also: http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/init-lists.html

Comment: Please read a basic tutorial or at least the C++ faq lite or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a c++ initialiser list.
You have it almost right, foo_(foo) is equivalent to foo_ = foo;

This is useful for when you have a member variable that does not have a default constructor.
Without this feature, you would have to make it a pointer.

The initialisations are also executed in the order that the members were declared in the class defenition, not the order they appear in (which should be the same as a matter of style, but isn't necessarily)

Comment: This is also required when you have const member variables and when calling base class constructors.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for.